# Symbol not found: _PyCapsule_Type flat namespace error from packaged PyQt4 package to OSx application

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4

I packaged the required PyQt4 into the pythonTool.App I made using [Playtypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

but still I am getting the error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 12, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt4/_qt.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCapsule_Type
  Referenced from: /Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt4/_qt.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/Gallery.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt4/_qt.so
```

here is the structure of my PythonTool.app OSx application.

```
Contents 
      \_ Info.plist
      \_ MacOS
            \_ Gallery
      \_ Resources
                \_ AppSettings.plist
                \_ MainMenu.nib
                \_ README.md
                \_ __init__.py
                \_ appIcon.icns
                \_ controlBar.py
                \_ exifread
                \_ gallery.py
                \_ icons.py
                \_ script
                \_ scripts
                \_ slideShow.py
                \_ slideShowBase.py
                \_ utils.py       
                \_ PyQt4
                      \_ Qt.so
                      \_ QtCore.so
                      \_ QtGui.so
                      \_ __init__.py
                      \_ _qt.so
                      \_ libQt.a
                      \_ libQtCore.a
                      \_ libQtGui.a
```